# Converting a readable date & time string to a datetime object in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, strptime

I am trying to convert a date and time string such as "Mar 15, 2016 10:47:15" into a Python datetime object using strptime. I believe I have the formatting correct however I still get a ValueError exception when I run the below:

```
>>> s = "Mar 15, 2016 10:47:15"
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(s,"%b %m, %Y %H:%M:%S")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'Mar 15, 2016 10:47:15' does not match format '%b %m, %Y %H:%M:%S'
```

Any ideas as to what may be wrong with my format string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second item in the format string (`%m`) refers to month. Changing it to `%d` will make your code work.

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(s,"%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Here are the relevant parts from [`strptime` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

> %d    Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number.   01, 02, ..., 31
>
> %m    Month as a zero-padded decimal number.  01, 02, ..., 12

Comment: Ugh, can't believe I missed that! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Month name is locale-specific. If you want to use english months names set for application English-based locale like `en_US`.

```
    $ env LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 python
    >>> import datetime
    >>> s = "Mar 15, 2016 10:47:15"
    >>> datetime.datetime.strptime(s,"%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S")
    datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 15, 10, 47, 15)
```

P.S. `%m` replaced with `%d`, which means day.